# Flutter iOS is not running

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods

I'm having trouble running my Flutter app on iOS (I'm using Mac M1). everything of mine seems to be installed. Though I don't know. This is my first time using Mac.
The problem is that whenever I try to run the ios it gives me this error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Fq0.png)

I ran Flutter Doctor and everything is ok which means my Cocoapod is installed(I might be mistaken though).

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESHqP.png)

However, when I open my project in Xcode, the `Pod` file is red. I don't know why.

[xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwfcU.jpg)

My homebrew is installed.

The Android part works well.

Comment: please show up your `xx/hitchride/ios/Podfile` content.

Comment: How do I get that please? I'm new to mac

Comment: in project directory go to ios folder where you will be able to locate Podfile

Answer (score 0):

try the following cmd in your VSCode terminal

Step 1: run in your project root folder

```
flutter clean
```

Step 2: run in your project root folder

```
cd ios && rm Podfile
```

Step 3: run in your project root folder

```
flutter pub get
```

Step 4: run in your project root folder

```
cd ios && pod update && pod install
```

if Step 4 doesn't works then try this, make sure you are in ios folder in terminal before running this: run in ios folder of your flutter project.

```
arch -x86_64 pod update && arch _x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: let me know if it doesn't work, then I will update the answer with another solution and more context.

Comment: when I tried the command "cd ios && rm Podfile", it gives me this error: "cd: no such file or directory: ios"

Comment: run these commands in root folder of your flutter project

Comment: now when I run "rm podfile" it's telling me "rm: Podfile: No such file or directory"

Comment: rm Podfile command is for deleting Podfile. looks like it's not there already, now continue from step 3 in from your root folder